# Fetch Relational data from parse

Tags: android, relational-database, parse-platform

I m working on parse. There are 2 table:
1. ScoreNode: User, score.
2. User: id, name, image(ParseFile)

Now need a query to fetch all the these info in one go.

```
ParseQuery<ScoreNode> query = new ParseQuery<ScoreNode>();
query.include("user");

How i can include image file?
query.include("user.image");
```

And query should be on scorenode.

Comment: To be honest I think you need to define a piece of Cloud Code for this query using the masterkey. As I recall you are not allowed to query Users directly from Android, not 100% sure though.

Comment: If so, you could also refactor the database to include a UserData[User,name,image,rel(ScoreNode)] object, which you indeed are free to query. The relation could simplify the query for presenting the users own scores and is just an optional addition.

Comment: But a user can have multiple ScoreNode then how can i create multiple column at run time....

Comment: As long as all User pointers in ScoreNode points to the same user, then you can query for all ScoreNodes owned by that User. If that is what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

regarding "scorenode.user"

if that is type pointer -> User object

and  User has the image field

Then you should be able to get everything but the image in one query by tagging on '?include=User' to the query on scorenode.

In Rest api its just a parm '?include= $pointer'

dont know syntax in android SDK.

A 2nd call will be needed to get the bitmap image itself. I think you can get the image URL from the first query and then just use that url getting a bitmap.